# PYTHON: How do I grab a specific part of a string?

Tags: python

I have the following string: "https://www.instagram.com/paula.mtzm/"
I want to put the user "paula.mtzm" to a variable.
Anyone know how to do this ? Maybe you can somehow delete a part of the string like "https://www.instagram.com/" and then delete the last character "/" ?

Comment: Usual method is to use regex; see the `re` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @alkasm: [`urlparse` is probably the better solution here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse). Worst case you just need to strip backslashes off after parsing. Regex should always be the last option, after simple string methods and dedicated parsers fail you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, especially for this case. For the question title though, the most general answer is regex. But yeah, good call out---parsing URLs in regex is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

```py
"https://www.instagram.com/paula.mtzm/".split(".com/")[-1].replace("/", "")
```

This should do what you want. Effectively it splits the string into a list using the separator `.com/`, gets the last item of that list (`"paula.mtzm/"`), and finally removes any remaining `/`s

I'm not sure how specific your use-case is so I don't know how suitable this is in general.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy:

Strings are indexed in Python just like a list.  So:

```
string = "potato"
print string[0] #this will print "p" to the console
#we can 'slice' in the index too
print string[0:3] #this will print "pot" to the console
```

So for your specific problem you could have your code search for the 3rd
forward slash and grab everything after that.

If you always know the web address you can just start your index at the end of
the address and where the user begins:

```
string = "https://www.instagram.com/paula.mtzm/"
string_index = 26 # the 'p' in paula begins here
user_name = string[string_index:string.len]
print user_name #outputs paula.mtzm
```

Comment: I doubt the poster was looking for an answer in python 2, as it's been unsupported for just under a year now.